# How can I find out the import path of external libraries in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-studio-import

I did the following:
1. downloaded a library from GitHub as zip and renamed it to jar
2. copied it in Android Studio to app->libs

How can I import it in the code or how can I find out the import paths?
The library is also in the build.gradle file in the app-folder: AndroidStudioProjects\CrypTradingJavaVersion\app

I'm very grateful for every help :-)
[import java.org.knowm.xchange.bitcoincharts.*;// that don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt3B1.png)

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imUEl.png)